# How to close the first window once if validate?

Tags: python, tkinter

How to do so that when validating the data, the first window closes and the second window continues in the loop. I appreciate your help 
this is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class VentanaP():
    """docstring for ClassName"""
    def __init__(self, maestro):
        self.maestro = maestro
        self.maestro.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % ( maestro.winfo_screenwidth(), maestro.winfo_screenheight()))
        self.maestro.config(bg="#3399CC")
        self.frame_login=Frame(self.maestro)
        self.frame_login.pack()

        self.boton_login=Button(self.frame_login,text="Login",command=self.Validar)
        self.boton_login.grid(row=5,column=0, padx=1,pady=10,sticky="e")

    def Validar(self):
        a="1"
        b="1"
        if a==b:
            self.nuevaVentana=Toplevel(self.maestro)
            self.app=VentanaS(self.nuevaVentana)
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo(message="Usuario o Contraseña\n Invalidos", title="Error", icon="info") 

class VentanaS():
    """docstring for VentanaS"""
    def __init__(self, raiz1):
        self.raiz1 = raiz1
        self.raiz1.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % ( raiz1.winfo_screenwidth(), raiz1.winfo_screenheight()))
        self.raiz1.config(bg="white")

raiz=Tk()
VentanaP(raiz)

raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Better switching frames instead of switching windows.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick. If you want to close the mainloop, you have to call on `self.meastro.destroy()` or if you want to make it visible `self.meastro.deiconify`. The state of the window will be withdrawn, so you might want to change that.

```
 def Validar(self):
        self.maestro.withdraw()
        a="1"
        b="1"
        if a==b:
            self.nuevaVentana=Toplevel(self.maestro)
            self.app=VentanaS(self.nuevaVentana)
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo(message="Usuario o Contraseña\n Invalidos", title="Error", icon="info")
```